# How do I get buildr to put dependencies on subprojects into the POM?

Tags: pom.xml, buildr

One of my Buildr buildfiles is structured like this:

```
require 'buildr/custom_pom'

# Omitting a lot of off-topic header stuff.
# Full version of the file is at GitHub.

desc 'Main project'
define 'hex' do
  project.version = VERSION_NUMBER
  project.group = 'org.trypticon.hex'

  pom.add_lgpl_v3_license
  pom.add_github_project('trejkaz/hex-components')
  pom.add_developer('trejkaz', 'Trejkaz', 'trejkaz@trypticon.org')

  desc 'Hex Utilities'
  define 'util' do
    pom.description = 'Utilities used by other hex components'
    compile.with INTELLIJ_ANNOTATIONS
    compile.with ICU4J
    compile.with SWINGX
    package :jar
    package :sources
    package :javadoc
  end

  #... omitting more ...

  desc 'Hex Viewer'
  define 'viewer' do
    pom.description = 'Hex viewer and related components'
    compile.with projects('anno', 'binary', 'interpreter', 'util')
    compile.with INTELLIJ_ANNOTATIONS
    compile.with SWINGX
    package :jar
    package :sources
    package :javadoc
  end
end
```

`hex-viewer` depends on `hex-util`. Yet when Buildr creates the POM, the POM is missing these dependencies between the subprojects.

Reading the source of Buildr itself, it seems that [they deliberately omit all dependencies which are not an `Artifact`](https://github.com/apache/buildr/blob/master/addon/buildr/custom_pom.rb#L216) for some reason. Subprojects not being artifacts, they naturally get omitted from the POM.

Is there a workaround to get them back in?

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BUILDR-486 for discussion and a fix. With Buildr 1.5 this issue will be fixed.

Comment: You can install our latest and greatest gem with `gem install buildr --pre`, and test the fix there.

Comment: NoMethodError : undefined method `to_spec_hash' for #<Buildr::ZipTask:0x007ff6912cfcb0>     - so I guess something I'm releasing is a zip and that's breaking it somewhere. https://gist.github.com/trejkaz/fb6531a3d0bf962044e956ed7d9ee8f2

Comment: At a dead end with diagnosing this one. Providing `buildr release --trace` doesn't propagate the trace setting through to `buildr upload`, preventing me from seeing what is going wrong. When I run `buildr upload`, that works fine. What does `buildr release` actually do?

Comment: One difference I see is that gpg signing is happening when I do buildr release but not when I do buildr upload... maybe gpg signing is screwed if the artifact is not a jar? :/

Comment: This is not related to this question - please file a bug with the project, give us a test case if possible. Don't forget to mention which version you're using.